# C++ Reading a txt file containing multiple kinds of variables

Tags: c++, string, file, int, loading

My skills are very basic. I'm trying to make save and load functions for a text game. This is my code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#include "variables.h"

// CORE FUNCTIONS
void save_game()
{
    std::ofstream file((savefile_path + "/" + player_name + ".txt").c_str());
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        file << engine_switch << std::endl;  //int
        file << map_switch << std::endl;     // int
        file << sub_map_switch << std::endl;  // int
        file << player_name << std::endl;  //string
        file << player_class << std::endl;  // string
        //file <<  << endl;
        file.close();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "A PROBLEM OCCURED";
        system("pause");
    }
    return;
}

void load_game()
{
    system("cls");

    std::cout << "ENTER THE SAVE FILE NAME (SAME AS YOUR CHARACTER NAME)\nOR PRESS ENTER TO GO BACK TO MAIN MENU: ";
    fflush(stdin);
    getline(std::cin, player_name);
    std::string name=player_name;
    std::ifstream file((savefile_path + "/" + player_name + ".txt").c_str());
    if(file)
    {
        file >> engine_switch; // this is int
        file >> map_switch; // this is int
        file >> sub_map_switch;  /this is int
        file >> player_name;  //string
        file >> player_class; //string
        //file >> ;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        if(player_name=="\0")
        {
            engine_switch=1;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            system("cls");

            std::cout << "COULDN'T OPEN THE SAVE FILE" << std::endl;
            system("pause");
            load_game();
        }
    }
    engine_switch=1;
    return;
}
```

The problem happens when I enter a player_name compound of multiple words separated with a space. For example when I enter "name name" the `player_name` becomes name and the `player_class` becomes name and the actual `player_class` is not put into any variable.

I tried the `rdbuf()` function, but didn't work and I don't even understand it yet. I tried it with `stream`, `string`, `c.str()`, everything I found on the web and could comprehend, but it always comes out wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you extract a string from a stream, spaces are considered as separators.
It's even worse: in your code, the `player_name` is followed by `player_class` which is also a string. How should your program interpret this :

```
10 15 20 John William Doe hero B
```

How would your program guess that `John William Doe` is a composed name and `hero B` the category ?

The simplest solution is to write all your strings on a separate line in the file.  When you load it you can then read it with [`getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/):

```
file >> engine_switch; // this is int
file >> map_switch; // this is int
file >> sub_map_switch;  /this is int
getline (file, player_name);  //string
getline (file, player_class; //string
```

Comment: Exactly.  But if you write a new line after each string, the input would read "Jowhn WIlliam Doe" skip the new line, and then read "hero B" in the second string.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. Misread your point. But on the re-read the code is exposed to the end of line left in the stream after `file >> sub_map_switch;`

Comment: Something must be still wrong because now my program reads player_name as player_class and player_name is empty. By the way it puts every word now, so it's good, but still not it.

Comment: Well, saw that coming. @Sumerechny add `file.ignore()` (or `file.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');` if you really want to be sure, but remember to `#include <limits>` to get `max`) after `file >> sub_map_switch;` to eat up the trailing end of line. Otherwise `getline` finds the end of line and returns immediately.

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't see that you already put a new lien after each of your fields.  So what happens, it that `file>>sub_map_switch` extracts the integer.  The next char to read is the trailing newline.  So in your case you first need to [`ignore()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/) the trailing newline before doing the `getline()`.  Attention the ignore is only needed when you do a `getline()` after a `>>` ; not between two `getline()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `getline` instead of the `>>` operator in your `load-game` function.

Instead of doing `file >> player_name` do `getline(file, player_name)`
This should be used in replacement of every occurrence of `file >> someVar`

**EDIT**: I didn't realize the others were integer values. For those you should still be using the `>>` operator.

Comment: What if all those information (`engine_switch`, `map_switch `, ...) are into one line?

Comment: I wrote something like this: std::getline(file, engine_switch);
        std::getline(file, map_switch);
        std::getline(file, sub_map_switch);
        std::getline(file, player_name);
        std::getline(file, player_class); and I get an error "no matching function for call to 'getline(std::ifstream&, int&'

Comment: Worth editing to add a note on the difficulties that can arise from mixing `std::getline` with `operator>>`, specifically `>>` leaving a linefeed in the buffer for `getline` to trip over.

Comment: @Sumerechny Sorry, that's my mistake. Notice the error message tells you whats wrong, getline doesn't accept integer values. I missed that in your code. So for those you will still need to use the `>>` operator.

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi Well then that's a poor design decision and would need to be separated by some other character, in which case you could add the third parameter to `getline` to only get up to that specified character.

Comment: @picklechips You are right. You should include this in your response.